# python date time get the current time but with seconds and hour and minute

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am able to get the current time as this:

```
import datetime
str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

that prints

> 2016-06-26

but i need to add the minutes and seconds and hour

i search on internet and people are suggesting using this:

```
str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"));
```

but actually the `%H:%M` returns `00:00` always

can you help ?

Comment: I suspect you misread the suggestions. A date doesn't have a time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2016-06-26 14:15:44'
```

You can even use [`.today()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) instead of [`.now()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

`datetime.date.today()` is of type `<type 'datetime.date'>` which basically returns only the date. That is why your hours and minutes when printed returns `00:00`.

Hence, if you use `datetime.datetime.now()` this would return type `<type 'datetime.datetime'>` which is a `datetime` object, you'll get the date and the time.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.date` only takes care of the date, you need to use `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the datetime.date object which doesn't contain any time.

You need to use 'datetime.datetime.now()'

Answer (score 1):

Try this: will return a String with Hour,Minutes and Seconds

```
datetime.datetime.now()..strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```